# Gwt how to make session listener?

Tags: spring, session, gwt

I'm making gwt + spring application. It's kind of game and i need to know if user leave the game. Is there any chance to check all sessions on the server side? 
I don't know if there is any already implemented mechanism, but i thought only about some event checker witch sends AsyncCallback to server once for 5 sec and i'll store list of this users somewhere on server.
Do you know any better idea to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Gwt does not have any mechanism to do what you want.

Although polling and saving sessions is an easy way to go, I would use a more modern approach, take a look to [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere) and [gwt-atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/tree/master/gwt20), and use server side utilities to track client connections.